# Initialize a List's Capacity

Tags: c#

I received my code review comments for the following method:

```
private RequiredDocumentEntity GenerateRequiredDocumentMapping(string documentTypeCode, params string[] alternativeDocumentIds)
{
    int alternativeDocumentCount = alternativeDocumentIds?.Length ?? 0;
    List<DocumentTypeEntity> satisfyingDocuments = new List<DocumentTypeEntity>(alternativeDocumentCount + 1);  // A document can always satisfy itself, hence the + 1
    DocumentTypeEntity documentType = null;

    if (documentTypeCode != null)
    {
        documentType = GetDocumentType(documentTypeCode);
        satisfyingDocuments.Add(documentType);
    }

    alternativeDocumentIds.Select(GetDocumentType)
                          .ForEach(satisfyingDocuments.Add);

    return new RequiredDocumentEntity() { SatisfiedBy = satisfyingDocuments };
}
```

The issue the reviewer had with this method was that the initialization of the list's capacity made the code difficult to read. It was also stated that it was a micro-optimization to save the list from doubling upon resize. This I agree with, to an extent. The list will have, at most 6, elements in it upon return. My argument against that would be that while it is a micro-optimization, if you can calculate how many elements will be in a list, why wouldn't you simply initialize the list's capacity?

Therefore, my question is:  Does the initialization as written make this code difficult to read?

Comment: The list capacity is really the smallest of all issues here. Much worse is the rest of the function.

Comment: Reviewing someone else's code review is not really what this site is intended for. I'd suggest to add context to clarify what this piece of code is meant to do, so that we can review it properly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to initialize the list's capacity and with only 6 items you won't notice any difference anyway so why making the code overcomplicated? As a matter of fact you need only a single query to get what you need so it's not only the capacity that makes it unecessarily more difficult to read by the entire implementation.

You can just *Concat* the `alternativeDocumentIds` to the optional `documentTypeCode`:

```
private RequiredDocumentEntity GenerateRequiredDocumentMapping(string documentTypeCode, params string[] alternativeDocumentIds)
{
    var satisfyingDocuments =
        from docId in 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentTypeCode) 
                ? Enumerable.Empty<string>()
                : new string[] { documentTypeCode }).Concat(alternativeDocumentIds)

        select GetDocumentType(docId);

    return new RequiredDocumentEntity()
    {
        SatisfiedBy = satisfyingDocuments.ToList()
    };
}
```

**but** if the the `documentTypeCode` is optional anyway why don't you simply include it in the `params` array? It doesn't make any difference for the result and the method becomes really simple:

```
private RequiredDocumentEntity GenerateRequiredDocumentMapping(params string[] documentIds)
{
    var satisfyingDocuments =
        from docId in documentIds
        where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(docId)
        select GetDocumentType(docId);

    return new RequiredDocumentEntity
    {
        SatisfiedBy = satisfyingDocuments.ToList()
    };
}
```

or

```
private RequiredDocumentEntity GenerateRequiredDocumentMapping(params string[] documentIds)
{
    return new RequiredDocumentEntity
    {
        SatisfiedBy = 
            documentIds
                .Where(docId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(docId))
                .Select(GetDocumentType).ToList()
    };
}
```

whatever you prefer.

Comment: `but if the the documentTypeCode is optional anyway why don't you simply include it in the params array?` Because _if_ it is passed, I want it to be the first item in the resulting array. If it were passed in the `params` argument, then I would have no way of knowing which in which index it were outside of relying on convention, which is an unreliable approach, IMO.

Comment: @KennethK. if you pass it first in the `params` it'll be first. linq does not change the order. there is nothing unreliable about it.

Comment: Neither the params nor linq will change any order here.

Comment: Certainly there is. If another developer comes behind me, they have to _know_ that the item should be passed first. Nothing about the method name nor the `params` modifier would indicate this.

Comment: @KennethK. if another developer comes behind you, they'll wonder why do they have to pass it first without any  obvious reason and they'll most probably will remove it. If the `RequiredDocumentEntity` had a dedicated property for it, I wouldn't mind but you just add it to a common list so everyone will wonder what's this for.